# Unity for UWP: An invalid handle was specified

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, signalr, il2cpp

I built my game for UWP with Il2Cpp. When it tries to connect to the internet I get this error:

> Exception thrown at 0x2121FE8A in game.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid
>   handle was specified.

Since the C# source turned into a C++ project I've no idea what's wrong in **my** code. it works errorless when I play in Unity.

How can I find a clue on what's going wrong?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not directly debug in the `c++` generated code ... it is very intransparent and hard to interpret (also the [Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsstore-debugging-il2cpp.html) doesn't really help here)

Rather build and deploy the app with the option `Wait for Managed Debugger` enabled and connect a Debugger in the c# VisualStudio solution ([source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/11/08/how-to-debug-unity-projects-with-il2cpp-backends-on-the-hololens/))

1. Set up your Unity project build settings and enable `Development Build`, `Script Debugging` and `Wait for managed debugger`

   [image]
2. Build in Unity, open the solution in VisualStudio instance and deploy it to a remote device
3. The build and deploy takes considerably longer and once deployed you're asked to attach the debugger

   [image]
4. Open any script in VisualStudio **from within Unity** (so you have the entire solution loaded correctly) and select `Attach Unity Debugger` from the drop down

   [image]
5. You should be prompted with a window that allows you to select the lens. (It should also work when the lens is attached via USB, but you might need to enable inbound UDP communication for devenv.exe)

   [image]

On this way you can debug your normal `c#` code, set breakpoints etc. while it is actually running the `Il2CPP` generated `c++` code.

Comment: Thanks.. it seems this is the solution. I did all the steps but it stuck on a white screen. I will try again with running on a remote device rather than the same machine.